# NLTK sentiment vader: build pie chart with scores

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, nltk

I am trying to understand how can I build a donut chart or pie chart from the scores I get. Below is my code

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

paragraph = "I loved the movie"          
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
ss = sid.polarity_scores(paragraph)
print(ss)
if ss["compound"] >= 0.5:
    print("positive")
elif ss["compound"] <= -0.5:
    print("negative")
else:
    print("neutral")

# myresults 
{'neg': 0.033, 'neu': 0.834, 'pos': 0.132, 'compound': 0.9936}
positive
```

How do I calculate all these values into percentages using the compound score? Right now I can only give it a positive, neutral or negative tag but I want the break up of all the values based on the compound score. For this example, the positive score should be in 99% and not 61.2% neutral, 0% negative and 38.8% positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `ss = {'neg': 0.033, 'neu': 0.834, 'pos': 0.132, 'compound': 0.9936}`, and
you want to have pie chart from the values of `neg`, `neu`, and `pos`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Try this

```
labels = ['negative', 'neutral', 'positive']
sizes  = [ss['neg'], ss['neu'], ss['pos']]
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%') # autopct='%1.1f%%' gives you percentages printed in every slice.
plt.axis('equal')  # Ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for the reply and that is not what I am looking for, sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question to show what output I am expecting.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. Hope you find the solution.